# issues installing magento extension

Tags: magento

i'm trying to install a magento extension in magento 1.8.1 community edition, but magento connect hangs at installing extension.  the package is downloaded into the app/code folder, but doesn't appear to go any further.  no error log entries created (there's an existing system.log, but no exception.log).

i've reset permissions per: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions

then i tried too install manually with "./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community [name_of_module]"

but downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command/Install.php on line 71-73 sets up $config->magento_root=dirname(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])); but the value seems to be blank (I'm guessing magento connect configures that somewhere)

how can i get either magento connect to work, or alternatively manually install the extension?

Answer (score 0):

First, generate the download link for the extension using http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

In order to obtain a download link, you have to generate a valid extension key in Magento Connect.

After manually downloading the extension, just unzip its content into Magento's app directory

Clean the cache and reload magento's main page, the extension should appear in administration under System->Configuration->Advanced

Hope this helps

Bye

Comment: fyi, that didn't work for us. we think our Magento installation must be really messed up.  thanks for the suggestion.